# Magento import price using custom module

Tags: csv, import, magento-1.9, price

I am going to create custom module for import price.

- created menu in admin
- under this created form with browse and submit button
- get csv file from using browse button and submitted it
- after clicking the submit button it goes to controller
- atlast it will import new price to the products that given in csv file

now i need controller action to do this stuff.

Any idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done the above job.

- created a form in admin and submit it to controller action.
- in controller action, i used simple import price method(like we do using play script)

it helped me.

Happiiee coding....